# WMI : MSVM_Imagemanagmentservice mount method does not assign drive letter

Tags: wmi

I m trying to mount a vhd on windows 2012 hyperV core datacenter edition. For mounting the vhd I m using the MSVM_Imagemanagementservice class and mount method inside that. The disk is mounted but the problem is no drive letter is getting assigned. I have tried it on other 2012 datacenter edition and 2012 core as well it works fine. i.e after mount the drive letter gets assigned.

Any thoughts on this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the drive letters list and then assign the drive letter as per your requirement. Given below is the function to get the drive letters list.

```
Function GetDriveLetterList(path)

    'Where path is path of VHD

    Dim mountedImage, diskDevice, diskPartition, diskPartitions, logicalPartition, timeout, query
    Dim logicalPartitionList

    timeout = 0
    driveLetterList = ""

    path = Replace(path,"\","\\")

    Set wmiServiceCIM = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")  

    Do
        WScript.Sleep(3000)
        timeout = timeout + 3

        Set mountedImage = (wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Msvm_MountedStorageImage WHERE Name='" & path & "'")).ItemIndex(0)

        query = "SELECT * From Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model='Msft Virtual Disk SCSI Disk Device' and SCSITargetId='" & mountedImage.TargetId & "' and SCSILogicalUnit='" & mountedImage.Lun & "' and SCSIPort='" & mountedImage.PortNumber & "'"
        Set diskDevice = wmiServiceCIM.ExecQuery(query).ItemIndex(0)

        query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {" & diskDevice.Path_.Path & "} where AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"

        Set diskPartitions = wmiServiceCIM.ExecQuery(query)

        For Each diskPartition In diskPartitions

            query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {" & diskPartition.Path_.Path & "} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
            Set logicalPartitionList = wmiServiceCIM.ExecQuery(query)
            If logicalPartitionList.count > 0 Then
                Set logicalPartition = logicalPartitionList.ItemIndex(0)
                'WScript.Echo logicalPartition.DeviceID
                driveLetterList = driveLetterList + logicalPartition.DeviceID
            End If

        Next
End Function
```

If you want to check for systems drive . Then you can do this ...

```
folderPath = driveLetter + ":\Windows\System32"

Set fileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FolderExists(folderPath) Then
    //doStuff
End If
```

Comment: The function above will give me drive letter which are currently being used. And based on that I can chose my letter. I hope I got this part correct. However, my problem is the mount method in MSVM_Imagemanagementservice class does not take any parameter for drive letter. The other method in root\virtualization\v2 namespace under same class is Attachvirtualdisk. this method also does not take any parameter for acception drive letter. However they have boolean which we can use to say whether drive letter needs to be assigned or not